# SQL: join 2 tables based on column value and select row values where grouped column value is max

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea

Ive got this query and I want to get all names from those clients that have the highest price of a day.
If multiple clients exist having the same max price, they shall be selected too.
I managed to get the customers with max price grouped by date but I dont think it gives me both customers if they have the same max value on the same day.
The names should be distinct.
The output needs to be as follows:

```
|   Name (asc)   |
------------------
| customer name |
| customer name |
| ......        |
```

The Orders table looks as follows:

```
|Client|Price|Orderdate |
------------------------
|1     |100.0|2010.01.10|
|...   |...  | .....    |

and the Client table:

|Client_NR|Name        |
-----------------------
|1        |customer#001|
|2        |customer#002|
```

```
select distinct  k1.NAME from  Orders a LEFT JOIN Order b on a.Orderdate = b.Orderdate
JOIN Client k1  on k1.Client_NR = a.Client
where a.Price IN 
(SELECT MAX(a.Price) from Order a group by Orderdate)

order by NAME asc
```

I presume my error lies within the Join Client line but I just cant figure it out.
Ive tried to use a.price = b.price in the first join but the test would fail.
Any advise is highly appreciated.

Comment: And note that `order` is a reserved word in MySQL, rendering it a poor choice as a table/column identifier

Comment: @Strawberry it should be Orders not order
I think Orders is not a reserved word.

Comment: Nevertheless, it's presently 'order'

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT Client.Name, 
                     RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Orders.Orderdate 
                                  ORDER BY Orders.Price DESC) rnk
              FROM Client 
              JOIN Orders ON Client.Client_NR = Orders.Client )
SELECT Name
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1
ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: Good to mention this works from MySQL 8.0 only.

Comment: @Milda OP have not specified the version - this mean that he has the last one.